# IntelliJ IDEA from Maven project doesn't build with Maven

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, manifest

I have a Web App and have done:

- Maven project IDEA > new > from source (maven project)
- Configured pom to generate Manifest entries:

  ```
     <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <executions>
              <execution>
                  <id>timestamp-property</id>
                  <goals>
                      <goal>timestamp-property</goal>
                  </goals>
                  <configuration>
                      <name>current.time</name>
                      <pattern>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z</pattern>
                      <timeZone>GMT+0</timeZone>
                  </configuration>
              </execution>
          </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.4</version>
          <executions>
              <execution>
                  <phase>validate</phase>
                  <goals>
                      <goal>create</goal>
                  </goals>
              </execution>
          </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
          <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.6</version>
          <configuration>
              <archive>
                  <manifest>
                      <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                      <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                  </manifest>
                  <manifestEntries>
                      <git-sha>${buildNumber}</git-sha>
                      <git-branch>${scmBranch}</git-branch>
                      <build-date>${current.time}</build-date>
                  </manifestEntries>
              </archive>
          </configuration>
      </plugin>
  ```

It works from the command-line and the Manifest has the desired entries.  Something like these:

```
git-branch: master
build-date: 2016-05-30 07:19:43 +0000
Implementation-Version: 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
git-sha: 7c248cbc66303e4e2574112049deef03a03856cd
```

When I choose the Maven lifecycles 'clean' and 'install' in IDEA and run them, the Manifest is also generated correctly.

But when I try to run the web app via a Run Configuration (configured with Tomcat), the Manifest contains the variables such as

```
git-branch: ${scmBranch}
build-date: ${current.time}
Implementation-Version: 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
git-sha:
```

I use these entries in the App.  I could use the command-line always but it makes it difficult to debug.

It seems that the IDEA Make is not using Maven.  Is there any way to get IDEA Make to run the Maven install or something else I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd previously written a 'solution of sorts' answer.  Now I have a better one so am editing this post.

It isn't obvious but you can add items to the 'Before Launch' box in the 'Run Configurations' (I've suggested to IntelliJ that they put explicit '+' and '-' against the box).  On the Mac hit `Command-N` and choose 'add Maven goal'.  I added 'clean package'.  Now the plugins are run and the Manifest properties are set.

[image: Run Configuration after adding maven goal]